# Executing an insert query on each row in results: psycopg2.ProgrammingError: no results to fetch

Tags: psycopg2, psql

What dumb thing am I missing here:

```
>>> cur.execute("select id from tracks")
>>> for row in cur:
...     story = random.choice(fortunes) + random.choice(fortunes)
...     cur.execute("update tracks set story=%s where id=%s", (story, row[0]))
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: no results to fetch
```

But there *seem* to be results:

```
>>> cur.execute("select id from tracks")
>>> for row in cur:
...     print(row)
... 
(8,)
(45,)
(12,)
(64,)
(1,)
(6,)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like psycopg2 doesn't allow interleaved queries (although PostgreSQL can do it, on the back end). If the initial query isn't huge, the simplest solution would be to coalesce the results into a list - just change `from row in cur:` to `from row in cur.fetchall():` and you should be right.